# Python CSV: reading rows terminated by comma results in an empty result

Tags: python, csv

If this is a stupid question, please feel free to harass me for not finding the correct answer on my own. I'm trying to read a CSV-formatted file that contains data on each row, and each row is terminated by a comma. Like this:

```
-1,
-1,
1,
1,
```

When I try to use Python's CSV-function, I use this code:

```
with open(waveform, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Which outputs the following:

```
['-1', '']
['-1', '']
['1', '']
['1', '']
```

I want it to ignore the empty char on each row. Do you have any advice?

Comment: If your file really is just a list of comma-terminated lines with only a single value on each line (and not really any values *separated* by commas), it seems to me that it's not really CSV and you shouldn't use the `csv` module at all...

Comment: @Wooble: It *is* valid, and the CSV module is doing exactly the right thing - each line contains two elements, one of which is the empty string. Even without the commas, it would be a valid CSV file (just one that only has one column).

Comment: @TimPietzcker, while it's true that it's technically valid CSV, there's no reason to use a CSV module to read single values from a line, when it's trivial to do it without an import at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore the last element in each line:

```
with open(waveform, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[:-1]
```

or convert each line into a dict:

```
columns = ['value']
with open(waveform, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rec = dict(zip(columns, row))
        print rec
```

prints

```
{'value': '-1'}
{'value': '-1'}
{'value': '1'}
{'value': '1'}
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. However, I'd like something that eliminates the problem from the beginning when reading the CSV-file, if it is possible.

Comment: @user1498553 - `csv.reader` works line after line independently and returns all elements within the line regardless of their count. So you have to work with each line independently.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with @eumiro's answer.

There's a `lineterminator=` option in `csv.reader` but apparently that's ignored at the moment..., so is a no-go.

If you *had to have* `csv.reader` not see a trailing field delimiter, then write a filter:

```
def remove_last_char(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        yield line.strip()[:-1]

with open(waveform, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader( remove_last_char(f) )
    for row in reader:
        print row[:-1]
```