# python CSV file reader adding an extra blank column

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that is generated by one of my clients and each row is a bunch of rows something like:

```
81.20414497158737,172.9103317265073,95.21067544500737,158.57147044650964,-84.25709905588982,-63.29849243164,-82.75973199495726,-61.30949985476218,-63.29849243164,-59.267658616873035,
```

Notice the `,` at the end of each row which is then followed by a carriage return.

The problem is that when I read it in python it generates an extra blank column. So, I read it as:

```
import csv
path = "path-to-file.csv"

with open(path) as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
```

This prints an example row as:

```
['81.91382020661584', '172.6194974551915', '95.000737839972', '157.5919980874564', '-83.09440263458094', '-63.29849243164', '-82.28324366654695', '-61.65345112997187', '-63.29849243164', '-57.6629400774182', '']
```

Note the extra blank column at the end.

Is there a way to work around this with the python CSV reader?

Comment: Can't you just remove the last item with `row = row[:-1]`?

Comment: It's a good idea. What I am not sure about is whether the client will do it consistently. I guess I can check if the last column is blank....

Comment: Yes, in that case, checking if the last element is empty before removing it is what I would do, too.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, ended up doing that. I asked the question as I was wondering if there was a way in the library to do this and I missed it in the docs.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503637/python-csv-reading-rows-terminated-by-comma-results-in-an-empty-result